# Bootstrap API Carousel Continuous

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I've been working with the Bootstrap API and I've been working on the carousel. I want to have a couple images "drift" across the page in a constant motion, with the next image starting on the right and move slowly across the page, when that one is  off the page, start the next one from the right. I do not want the image to ever stop. I've tried to use some of the options such as `interval`, `pause`, and `wrap` but to no avail. Is there a way to achieve this with the default carousel?

```
<!--  Carousel -->  
        <div id="this-carousel-id" class="carousel slide"><!-- class of slide for animation -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="text-center item active"><!-- class of active since it's the first item -->
                    <img src="<?php realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]); ?>/public_html/img/phone_slide.png" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="<?php realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]); ?>/public_html/img/phone_slide.png" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->
        </div>
<!-- /Carousel -->

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({interval: 500});
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you paste the code that you use currently ? it would greatly help.

Comment: Sure, just posted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override Bootstrap's CSS so that it uses a linear transition instead of an ease-in-out. You can also change its duration from 0.6s to whatever you want. Obviously the more seconds the longer/slower the transitions will be. You will also want to make your interval 1 so that the carousel does not stop on any image.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/P9sR3/)

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition: 5s linear left;
    -moz-transition: 5s linear left;
    -o-transition: 5s linear left;
    transition: 5s linear left;
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad it is what you were looking for!

Comment: One more thing, It seems to jump and restart at some point. Sometimes it will scroll smooth for 3 iterations, 4, sometimes 5, and then it will reload. Any idea what might be happening there?

Comment: @TrevorHutto I'm not experience that in Firefox. I let it run about 10 iterations and it seems good to me.

Comment: It is happening in Safari, must be something else in my code.

Comment: I did transition of 18 seconds and data-interval of 1000 (which I think is 1 second) and it worked pretty good but was still a tiny bit glitchy, meaning it shimmered a tiny bit now and again... I tried data-interval of just 1 and it was more shimmery... and I did data-interval of 1800 and it was in between 1000 and 1 I would say... ever so slight... I wonder how to improve on that... I am not sure if I am going to keep it... the glitch-y-ness is so slight it is hard to decide... i tried setting them to the same 4s and data-interval=4000 or  8 and 8000 and it seemed more glitchy...