# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel - How to implement a continuous slow scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3 and have got a carousel working of 8 images. It shows 4, then jumps to the next 4. At the moment, one must use the left and right arrow buttons (or wait a few moments) for the carousel to change. How can I make it so there is a continuous, slow scroll through the items in the carousel? I don't want it to jump from set of 4 to the next, I want a continuous scroll.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap API Carousel Continuous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276481/bootstrap-api-carousel-continuous)

Comment: In that example, the carousel scrolls to the left for some time, then starts feeding it back from the left - I want this to go from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is copy and paste the following code into your HTML file. You’re encouraged to change the carousel-example-generic id to something more unique. If you do, make sure to reference it properly throughout the markup. We also used placeholder images that you’ll need to replace with your desired slider images.

http://jsfiddle.net/2qWy8/21/

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="5"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="6"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
         <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
              <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
                   <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
                        <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div> <!-- Carousel -->
```

There is also solution with JS, but tell me and i will edit my answer, is this what you need?

**UPDATE** 
Then use another widget, not this one

Here is reference to plugin

http://www.codicode.com/demo/endless_scroll/\

Use like this

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#divID").endlessScroll({ width: '100%', height: '100px', steps: -2, speed: 40, mousestop: true });
});
```

Comment: Thank-you for your reply. No, not exactly what I need. I need to carousel to do a continuous scroll. Basically, I don't want a pause when the carousel changes to a new item.